# Recreating the Pound-Rebka (Harvard Tower) Experiment

Tags: general-relativity, experimental-physics

For my senior lab I am thinking of recreating the Pound-Rebka experiment. Does anyone know if this has been done in a pedagogical setting before and/or knows any resources that would be helpful in recreating this experiment?

Comment: Measured frequency shift of Pound–Rebka experiment $\Delta f/f\sim 10^{-15}$. I do not think that this kind of precision could be expected from a senior lab project.